# Can you obtain more than two vertex covers from a bipartite graph using a max-flow algorithm?

Tags: graphs

Applying a max-flow algorithm to the graph it's trivially possible to find one or two vertex covers, inverting source and sink and the directions of the flows. Is it possible to find more?

Comment: In a graph with 2 vertexes and 1 edge between them, there exist 2 different vertex covers, correct? Or do you mean vertex cover size? But it's equal to number of edges in a maximum matching.

Comment: You're right. I meant executing a max-flow algorithm without inverting source and sink (and edge directions).

Comment: I must be not getting it. If you're looking for a cover from only one partition, then there exists only 1 cover for a partition - all the vertexes that have an incident edge, and 1 more cover in the other partition. But if you can combine the partitions, you will have more covers.

Comment: That's the point: what do you mean by "combine partitions" (I guess you mean cuts)? Can you provide an example? I'm probably the one not getting it.
It seems to me that even trying with different partitions, you always get the same vertex cover (or the same two, if you like).

Comment: In a graph with 4 vertexes, 2 partitions: `[a,c]` and `[b,d]` and 2 edges `[(a,b), (c,d)]`, there are 4 different vertex covers: `[a,b], [c,d], [b,c], [a,d]`.

Comment: @VictorSergienko: I think you mean 4 different vertex covers [a,c], [a,d], [b,c], [b,d].  (E.g. your cover [a,b] covers the (a,b) edge twice and leaves the other edge uncovered.)

Comment: You're perfectly right, but I asked for the specific case when you use a max-flow algorithm to find the vertex cover. Using such a method, in this case you'd only find [a,c] or [b,d].